# Spring Security: hasAuthority,hasRole and PreAuthorize does not work

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to test my web api thats secured using the standard Spring Security annotations and methods.
I reviewed all the options on the site, nothing helped, here is the code. Without roles, everything works fine.I have been suffering for several days with this problem.I will be grateful for the help, thanks.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImp userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/authenticate").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/userData").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/allUsers").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
                http.addFilterAfter(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImp userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/userData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello new User";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/allUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<UserD> findAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest jwtRequest) throws Exception{
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRequest.getName(), jwtRequest.getPassword()));
        }catch(BadCredentialsException e){
            throw new Exception("Incorrect username and password", e);
            }
        final UserD userD = (UserD)userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(jwtRequest.getName());

        final String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(userD.getName(), userD.getRole());

        Map<Object, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
        model.put("username", jwtRequest.getName());
        model.put("token", token);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
    }
}
```

If `antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/allUsers").permitAll()`
,then it returns users as it should

UserDetailsServiceImp

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImp implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findByName(username).get(0);
    }
}
```

and User data with the addition of roles

```
@Component
public class DataInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        UserD user = new UserD();
        user.setName("user");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("password"));
        user.setRole("ROLE_USER");
        userRepository.save(user);

        UserD admin = new UserD();
        admin.setName("admin");
        admin.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("password"));
        admin.setRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
        userRepository.save(admin);
     }
}
```

this is what the database returns

[image: response on this url]

Answer (score 0):

I want to clarify something first, which may help you to pinpoint the issue:

does your UserDetailsServiceImp retrieve username and role from database or LDAP or other repository?
what role is retrieved from database or LDAP or other repository?
does it have prefix "ROLE_" already or not?

if the role retrieved from database is "ADMIN", you shall not add ROLE_ by yourself when you call hasAuthority().

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/allUsers").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
```

And if it is not the case, enable the debug in the log, to see what is exactly going on with the /allUsers request.

---

UPDATE:
And one thing i suspected was your implementation of UserDetailsServiceImp.

You have to make sure the role was set into user details.
in your implementation, it seems that you queried out from DB directly, not sure if you set the role into the userDetails.

```
return userRepository.findByName(username).get(0);
```

Here is something it should happen:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    //assume, there is only one user with the username
    UserD user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    //assume, there is only one role for the user
    roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole()));
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
                roles);
    }
```

Comment: I think your implementation of UserDetailsServiceImp may have issue, please make sure it set the granted Authorities into the user in your "loadUserByUsername" method.

Comment: I have also updated the answer to show how to set the granted authorities.

Comment: I added a screenshot